# Checking for palindrome between two indices

Tags: c++, palindrome

I am trying to check whether a the string contains palindrome between the given indices. However I am unable to find the bug in my code.

```
bool isPal(char a[],int i,int j){

    for(int k=i;k<(j-i)/2;k++)
        if(a[k]!=a[j--])
            return 0;

    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You error was to increment `j` as but also assume (in the loop condition) that it remains at its input value. You could use the input variables also as loop variables

```
bool isPalindrome(const char*a, int i, int j) {
    while(i<j)
        if(a[i++] != a[j--])
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

when setting the correct stop conditions for the loop is straightforward.

Answer (score 4):

You are changing the value of j using `j--`, which will affect the condition of your for loop `k<(j-1)`

Answer (score 2):

You modify `j` inside the loop, changing also the end condition (which were incorrect anyway), you might use instead:

```
bool isPal(const char a[],int i,int j){
    for (int k = 0; k < (j - i) / 2 ; k++) {
        if (a[i + k] != a[j - k]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Minimal change from your code would be:

```
bool isPal(char a[], int i, int j)
{
    const int mid_index = (j + i) / 2;
    for (int k = i; k < mid_index; k++)
        if (a[k] != a[j--])
            return 0;

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution but what is wrong with my indexing ?

Comment: @generic_opto_guy: `j - i` is the length of the "string view". `(i+j)/2` is the index of middle of that "string view". I iterate over (half) length, not over index as OP.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int k=i;k<(j-i)/2;k++)
```

You're starting at i and then going up to j-i-1. This is not what you want. Replace i and j with some values and you'll see.